# unable to send parameter through ajax to a page itself

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am sending parameter to a page itself on keyup event.

I am sending a parameter though ajax like `url:"http://localhost/application/views/pages/users/tags.php?tagfilter=lif",`

and getting its value in a javascript function `('/instruction/showtags/<?php if( isset($_GET['tagfilter']) && $_GET['tagfilter'] == "") {echo $_GET['tagfilter'];} ?> ', {`

I checked,my console , its showing no errors & no warning.
But i am sure its either not sending parameter or it may be its not getting the parameter.

Please let me know , why my parameter is not sending ? Is the way of writing ajax code is correct?

*If you could not understand my question, then please let me know,  i will try to explain it in some other way.*

Full Source code:

**tags.php**

```
 <input placeholder="Search" id="tagfilter" name="tagfilter" type="text"/>
```

**Jquery/ajax function**

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
      $(document).ready(function() {    
      $('#tagfilter').keyup(function(e){
       // alert("called"); 
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://localhost/application/views/pages/users/tags.php?   
       tagfilter=lif",
            type:"get",  
            success: function(){ 

            } 
        });
    });
 });     
</script>
```

My **Infinite scroll js file**, including in the same page

```
 <script>
         (function($) { 
                $.fn.scrollPagination = function(options) {

                        var settings = { 
                                nop     : 10, // The number of posts per scroll to be loaded
                                offset  : 0, // Initial offset, begins at 0 in this case
                                error   : 'No More Data To Display!', // When the user reaches the end this is the message that is
                                                            // displayed. You can change this if you want.
                                delay   : 500, // When you scroll down the posts will load after a delayed amount of time.
                                               // This is mainly for usability concerns. You can alter this as you see fit
                                scroll  : true // The main bit, if set to false posts will not load as the user scrolls. 
                                               // but will still load if the user clicks.
                        }

                         .............................
                         .............................
                         .............................
```

**Update:**

What exactly i am trying to do?

---

I have implemented a infinite scroll with jquery. When my page loads, it call my controller, and from from controller it takes data and display it in my view page.

Now , i plan to put search on  this page with infinite scroll.
I have a textbox, from this textbox i am trying to do search on keyup event.

I am trying with this logic. If you have any better logic, please share with me,because i am struggling from long time to implement this.

---

Comment: in your code at the top, should it not be `$_GET['tagfilter'] != ""`? (note `!=`)

Comment: @JerrySeeger I could not understood your words. Please tell it in some other way. Thank you

Comment: Just curious: do you upvote your own questions with [your other account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1487400/ashutosh)?

Comment: `if( isset($_GET['tagfilter']) && $_GET['tagfilter'] == "")` should be `if( isset($_GET['tagfilter']) && $_GET['tagfilter'] != "")`

Comment: why you're sending `$_GET` in Ci when you can use segments. I think you are having a problem with your way of implementing your idea.
please describe your idea in details so we can help more

Comment: Expanding on what @mamdouh mentioned, $_GET is disabled by default in CodeIgniter, partly for security and partly because there are better ways to pass data.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan  Update: i  described my idea in details in above question. Please have a look once again.

Comment: @JerrySeeger Can you please help me. Please read my question once again. i update few things there

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan  I even tried to pass parameter like this `url:"http://localhost/instruction/tags/lif",` and get it like this  `$.post('/instruction/showtags/<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3) ?> ', {`     . But still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I don't know your structure so what I have is few tips.

First: you need to know that javascript processing is much faster than PHP as long as JS is a **Client Side** language when PHP is **Server Side** language. so try to keep your php data in javascript vars like this:

```
var seg3 = "<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3) ?>";
$.post("/instruction/showtags/" + seg3, {...etc
```

then for your safety just try to check whether you need all the url not just part of it ( depends on CI configuration ) so your code can come up like this

```
var seg3 = "<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3) ?>";
var myurl = "<?php echo site_url('casting/send_email'); ?>" + seg3;
$.post(myurl, {...etc
```

And be sure not to use `$_GET`.

Second, make sure you're sending the segment and it's there. you can always use the 
`console.log()` in javascript to keep up with the data and see if it's empty or not.

whether you want it on keyup or keydown or whatever it will be the same.

and if you are using **json** make sure to add it as the last arg to your `$.post()` method you can see the **[jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)** for it.

Answer (score 0):

You check if `$_GET['tagfilter'] == ""`, and only if the string is empty you print it.
so it should be:

```
<?php if( isset($_GET['tagfilter']) && $_GET['tagfilter'] != "") { echo $_GET['tagfilter'];} ?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you know PHP is serverside and only executed once you load the javascript, this could be the problem.

Comment: Yeah, this is the problem. Do you any idea how to do this work in some with some other techniques?

Comment: You should have a look at jQuery-ajax-function to transmit your data to the server and get an answer: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: But you are already using $.post that should also work. So $_GET['tag..'] is the tag that was in the query-string on pageload, e.g. index.php?tag=test